# Using fields/variable in Factory class to be used across objects created through factory

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I am using **Factory** to create my objects like following, here both `MyObject` and `YourObject` classes implements `MyInterface`:

```
public class MyFactory {
    public static MyInterface myObject(int value, int commonValue) {
        return new MyObject(value, commonValue);
    }

    public static MyInterface yourObject(String str, int commonValue) {
        return new YourObject(str, commonValue);
    }
}
```

I want to set `commonValue` at the factory level instead of passing them as parameters in individual methods, as the same value is passed to create set of objects using factory. Also once I create one set of objects using the factory I want to reset `commonValue` to its default so that previously set value is not used by default later on.
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `commonValue` can change, a cleaner way (IMHO) would be:

```
public class MyFactory {
    private final int commonValue;
    public MyFactory (int commonValue) { this.commonValue = commonValue; }

    public MyInterface myObject(int value) {
        return new MyObject(value, commonValue);
    }

    public MyInterface yourObject(String str) {
        return new YourObject(str, commonValue);
    }
}
```

And when you need to reset it, just create a new factory.

The benefits are:

- it is clear what the value is (if you used a mutable value with a setter, some code could affect non related code)
- it is thread safe

Comment: How would this implementation help to ".. reset `commonValue` to its default ..." ? Maybe `final` modifier should not be used and a default value might be set for `commonValue` attribute, using an `defaultValue` attribute as `final` instead. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FlavioCysne to reset the value, you create a new factory: `MyFactory reset = new MyFactory(defaultValue);`. That suggestion may not be applicable to the op's use case but if it is, I think it's better than a mutable factory with a `reset` method which would have error-prone side effects...

Comment: I think this solution would work for me as this does provide the resetting I need, Thanks +1

Answer (score -1):

I use the Spring framework to do exactly that kind of thing. Let's me set up my factories up front and then construct from them. Is this an option?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am looking at a little simpler solution without using frameworks.